# How to neatly assign multiple different values to multiple different variables?

Tags: python

So basically I want to assign a lot of values to a lot of variables. I'm using Python 3, trying to assign different symbols to a grid for a pygame project. I'd like to be able to do it with a 'for' loop, but I've been wracking my brain trying to figure it out for a while now. University class, you know what you're dealing with lol.

Warning: Wall of text below. This is why I wanna see if I can shorten it, lol

```
# assign file destinations to variables
      image1 = ('\image1.bmp')
      image2 = ('\image2.bmp')
      image3 = ('\image3.bmp')
      image4 = ('\image4.bmp')
      image5 = ('\image5.bmp')
      image6 = ('\image6.bmp')
      image7 = ('\image7.bmp')
      image8 = ('\image8.bmp')

      # make a list of the images; each image is there twice so there are pairs
      img_list = []
      img_list.append(image1)
      img_list.append(image1)
      img_list.append(image2)
      img_list.append(image2)
      img_list.append(image3)
      img_list.append(image3)
      img_list.append(image4)
      img_list.append(image4)
      img_list.append(image5)
      img_list.append(image5)
      img_list.append(image6)
      img_list.append(image6)
      img_list.append(image7)
      img_list.append(image7)
      img_list.append(image8)
      img_list.append(image8)  
      random.shuffle(img_list)

      # grid coordinates
      x1 = 5
      x2 = 110
      x3 = 215
      x4 = 320      

      # assign tiles to locations on the window
      self.tile1 = Tile([x1, x1], img_list[0], self.surface)
      self.tile2 = Tile([x2, x1], img_list[1], self.surface)
      self.tile3 = Tile([x3, x1], img_list[2], self.surface)
      self.tile4 = Tile([x4, x1], img_list[3], self.surface)
      self.tile5 = Tile([x1, x2], img_list[4], self.surface)
      self.tile6 = Tile([x1, x3], img_list[5], self.surface)
      self.tile7 = Tile([x1, x4], img_list[6], self.surface)
      self.tile8 = Tile([x2, x2], img_list[7], self.surface)
      self.tile9 = Tile([x2, x3], img_list[8], self.surface)
      self.tile10 = Tile([x2, x4], img_list[9], self.surface)
      self.tile11 = Tile([x3, x2], img_list[10], self.surface)
      self.tile12 = Tile([x3, x3], img_list[11], self.surface)
      self.tile13 = Tile([x3, x4], img_list[12], self.surface)
      self.tile14 = Tile([x4, x2], img_list[13], self.surface)
      self.tile15 = Tile([x4, x3], img_list[14], self.surface)
      self.tile16 = Tile([x4, x4], img_list[15], self.surface)
```

Comment: `images = [f'\image{i}.bmp' for i in range(1,9)]`. Don't create `image1`, `image2`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton chepner, that's perfect!

Comment: @chepner Can you elaborate an answer so the OP can accept it?

Comment: The question is off-topic for Stack Overflow; requests for improvements belong on codereview.stackexchange.com. Setting `images` was just some low-hanging fruit to suggest the kind of improvements that can be made.